# Almost isometric manifolds are diffeomorphic

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-structures

I am looking for a reference to the following statement.
(It should be known --- I saw it before, don't remember where; search by keywords did not help.)

> Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a homeomorphism between two smooth $d$-dimensional manifolds.
> Suppose that $M$ and $N$ admit Riemannian metrics such that the $f$ is $e^{\mp\varepsilon}$-bi-Lipschitz for some $\varepsilon=\varepsilon(d)$.
> Then $M$ is diffeomorphic to $N$.

(It can be proved by taking a locally finite covering of manifolds by almost isometric charts and applying a smoothing in the charts recursively.)

Comment: Is this what you want?  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864199001455

Comment: Oh sorry, the contents of this paper were apparently mischaracterized in the thread I found it in.

Comment: Mathoverflow asks "Know someone who can answer?". Yes, Anton Petrunin should know the answer to this question.

Comment: @dodd, I’m sure Anton knows how to prove it, but he doesn’t necessarily know a reference.

Comment: I guess it’s not in Gromov’s book on metric structures?

Comment: @DeaneYang I do not think so, but it could be mentioned there.

Comment: This is a curvature free fact, so maybe ask one of the experts in that area?

Comment: @DeaneYang, It is essentially differential topology, metric here only simplifies formulation. Likely quasiconformal-mapping people know the answer.

Comment: Did you check Ferrand's papers?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I just made a search but did not find anything related (I might miss something).